# Refresh SPAN content automatically

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck in a problem here that I tried all google answers and nothing did this work out. Specially because I prefer to do a pure JavaScript solution if possible... I have a menu, with a cart. This menu shows something like: Your cart (0)
where 0 is the number of items inside the cart. The items number are query from a SQL table 'cart', where I save all users products added to cart. So they don't lose the items on cart when the session closes. But I want to update this menu span everytime they add something inside the cart, without the need to refresh the page. The items are being added this way:

In the table where products are displayed I have:

```
<td id="add'.htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'"> <label><a href="javascript:addtocart('.htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').')"><b><img src="/img/cart.gif" /></b></a></label> </td>
```

so I call javascript:addtocart passing 'id' of the product as parameter. This function does:

```
function addtocart(id)
{
    document.getElementById('add'+id).innerHTML='<b>On your cart!</b>';
    load('/index.php?addtocart&id='+id);
}
```

Ok, function load does:

```
function load(url) {
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        eval( xmlhttp.responseText );
    }
}

xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

OK, so we have my index.php receiving the GET with id of the product to add to cart, and I do on index.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['addtocart']) && isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO cart VALUES('$id', '$userid')");           
}
```

This is working very well, and if I refresh the page, in the menu I get "Your cart (1)"... But how to do this refresh automatically when the client clicks on the table? Possible with pure javascript function?

//EDIT for index.php content:

```
<?php
    include("./includes/header.php");
    include("./includes/db.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>MyShop</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function load(url) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function addtocart(id)
    {
        document.getElementById('add'+id).innerHTML='<b>On your cart!</b>';
        load('/index.php?addtocart&id='+id);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="home">
    <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
    <div id="container">
        <?php 
            if (isset($_GET['news']))
            {
                include 'news.php';         
            }
            else if (isset($_GET['orders']))
            {
                include 'orders.php';           
            }
            else if (isset($_GET['addtocart']) && isset($_GET['id']))
            {
                $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO cart VALUES('$id', '$userid')");           
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `index.php` page, return the number of products inserted for the current user and then use the success handler of the ajax call to update the span.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        // here get the number of products inserted and display in span
        document.getElementById('span_id').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

## EDIT

Do not make the ajax call to the same page. Have the `id` sent to some other page, let's say `abc.php`. Then keep only the php related code inside your `update_cart_ajax.php` page.

So your `addtocart()` becomes:

```
function addtocart(id)
{
    document.getElementById('add'+id).innerHTML='<b>On your cart!</b>';
    load('/update_cart_ajax.php?addtocart&id='+id);
}
```

## update_cart_ajax.php

```
<?php          
include("./includes/db.php");
if (isset($_GET['addtocart']) && isset($_GET['id']))
{
   $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO cart VALUES('$id', '$userid')");           
}
else
{
    echo 0;
    exit;
}
// get the number of products added to the cart for the current user
$total_products_in_cart = <value returned from db>;
echo $total_products_in_cart;
exit;
```

Comment: I should leave the
`eval( xmlhttp.responseText );`
or no? And the problem is that the get answer from index.php returns the entire body and not only the number of items...

Comment: Yes, remove the `eval` line. Also will need to see `index.php` to know why it's happening so

Comment: check the original post please. the menu.php is where i have the Your cart (N) info...

Comment: You're making the ajax call to the same page? i.e. your add to cart image is present in index.php?

Comment: yes is into the include orders.php.. there i have a table with the products and the cart image that call the javascript function.

Comment: Hi asprin, I'm back... It's working, but sometimes (often when I click too fast on the cart icon, but not necessarily) it doesn't add. I'm working on localhost, so I think it should process the request really quick. If is bogus on localhost I imagine when I do via remote connection. Can be done something about this? XML have some kind of QUEUE?

Comment: Sorry, the last question here was wrong. The bogus came because I was adding for test the same product ID in cart. When the ID is a unique table. It's working, thanks for the help!